# Pages built with Elementor lose their styling

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am working on a website based on Wordpress and the theme Pro by ThemeCo. 
A lot of my pages are built with the Elementor Plugin and are styled with the tools provided by the Elementor interface.

At random times, some of the pages I've already styled lose their styling. 
The structure and the widget are ok, but all the styling I made disapear.

*Here is an exemple of a page which have lose its styling :*

[image: page without styling]

*Here is the way it should look*

[image: page with styling]

To have the styling back, I just update the page with Elementor builder.

***My question is :*** Why is this happening ?
Is it something related with the cache ?

have a nice day

Comment: Elementor stores a lot of the styling in CSS files stored under `/uploads`. Could it be that something is wiping those files? It could help to know what is *gone* from the page when the styling is wrong (e.g. a CSS file is missing or the file that should have the styles doesn't).

Comment: Can we see your console on the page that errors to make sure you dont have a error in there please. 
chrome windows : Ctrl Shift J
chrome Mac : CMD Option J

Comment: Hey, I have indeed some errors 
'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)', and it seems it failed to load some CSS stored under '/uploads'

I have this error two times in my console.
I've just updated my page and that's weird because the css is back !